# Efficient method to add values in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, addition

I am trying to determine a more efficient to add specific values in a `pandas df`.

For the `df` below, I want to add the `integers` in `Value` for each `X + Y` in `Area`. So, for every `X`, I want to add that to the following `Y`.

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'Area' : ['X','Y','Z','X','Y','Z'],                                     
    'Value' : [10,11,20,21,30,31],                                     
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

If there's not many values I can go through manually as per the following:

```
x = df.iloc[0] + df.iloc[1]
```

But if the `df` is quite large, this becomes inefficient.

Intended Output:

```
21
51
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to `Series`, create default index and [`Series.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html):

```
s1 = df.loc[df['Area'].eq('X'), 'Value'].reset_index(drop=True)
s2 = df.loc[df['Area'].eq('Y'), 'Value'].reset_index(drop=True)

s = s1.add(s2)
print (s)
0    21
1    51
dtype: int64
```

Advantage of solution is not important ordering of `X` and `Y` values.

Answer (score 1):

create a mask with `X` and `Y` and groupby on every 2 indexes and `sum()`, use:

```
m=df[df.Area.isin(['X','Y'])].reset_index(drop=True)
print(m.groupby(m.index//2)['Value'].sum())
```

***Output***

```
   0    21
   1    51
```